# python singleton metaclass dict vs non dict

Tags: python, singleton

I'm trying to extend my python knowledge. So I just wrote my very first singleton metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None    

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

I just checked (for feedback) the good old stackoverflow. Lets see 'how others do it' and I found this solution:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}    

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Can somebody explain me why (the hack) do we need that dictionary?

Comment: possibly something to do with recursion of classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to support inheritance. Using your solution, inheriting from a class built with the `Singleton` metaclass does not allow the subclass to have its own singelton.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None    

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class FirstSingleton(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

class SecondSingleton(FirstSingleton):
    pass

x = FirstSingleton()
y = SecondSingleton()

x is y # True
```

As you see, the calls `FirstSingleton()` and `SecondSingleton()` both returned the same instance.

But using a dictionary allows a class and its subclasses to have different singletons.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class FirstSingleton(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

class SecondSingleton(FirstSingleton):
    pass

x = FirstSingleton()
y = SecondSingleton()

x is y # False
```

The class and the subclass each returned their own instance of a singleton.